# How will cities be transformed after hover cars become common?

Tags: cities, near-future, architecture, transportation

Lets use New York as an example because it's iconic. The city's road network is placed within clear blocks.
Now, in near future, some 50 to 100 years from now, hover cars are reality and so common that wheeled vehicles are deemed illegal to use on city roads. The hover cars are allowed to hover from five to hundred meters of the ground, they don't have to follow the roads as closely as modern wheeled cars either. The hover cars hover by using small jet thrusters - which are slightly more noisy than modern car engines. In case of malfunction, the vehicle launches a protective foam around the vehicle just before impact.

This allows the city to, well, not exactly neglect the maintenance on the roads used by cars but to use less funds on the maintenance.

So, now I'm wondering how this will shape the cities that existed before hover cars were invented. It allows more leg room for pedestrians but what else that brings to the plate?
Also assume that the hover cars became common about 20 years ago and wheeled vehicles were banned from entering cities 10 years ago. However, the wheeled vehicles are still allowed to be used outside city limits.
Using New York as the example, how much the city would change? Your answer doesn't have to be about New York but you can use it as an example.

This question on how [anti-gravity might change cities and buildings](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/how-would-antigravity-change-the-design-of-cities-and-buildings) might be close to my question but not exactly.

The question about [Urban Planning in 3-Dimensions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/18638/urban-planning-in-3-dimensions) seems to focus on new cities and the cars itself, I'm more interested on the old cities and only the cities themself.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate because you can apply the same ideas as were given in the answers to the question @o.m. found to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well I would guess that streets would become public thoroughfares for pedestrians and other small vehicles like bicycles, roller blades and hoveround type personal transport.

First people would start using the streets for many things, and then the streets would likely be roofed over at one or two stories, the 'homeless' would now have protection from the weather etc...

The roofs of these roads would also allow for pedestrian traffic that is open to the elements. and people might also start using this for growing things, parks, gardens etc. to help feed people, improve living conditions etc.

Where buildings are much taller in downtown, Many of the buildings will be connected much higher and using the space for many different things still including individual transport.  "subways" would likely be at multiple levels traveling around the city (like horizontal elevators), pushing the 'outside' up higher and higher.  eventually the city might look like a large hilly park with buildings poking out through them.  Can have water parks in the summer and downhill skiing in the winter right on the city.

This might take closer to 50 years after.  Most of the buildings that poke out are likely going to be flying car parks or stations to get on the subway systems.